# azure data factory pipeline customise schedule

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have some Azure Data Factory Pipelines that I would like to run once per day except the 1st day of the month.

An example is if it is 1st December 2016 I would like pipeline to NOT run.

Is this something possible by simply changing the pipeline Schedule? If not what is the other option to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for now is to create Custom Pipeline in which every time it is started, you check the date and if it is 1st of the month you just finish it, by returning null from Execute method you must implement in Custom pipeline.

EDIT AFTER COMMENT:

```
public IDictionary<string, string> Execute(IEnumerable<LinkedService> linkedServices, IEnumerable<Dataset> datasets, Activity activity, IActivityLogger logger)
{
    if (DateTime.UtcNow.Day == MonthDay.One)
    {
        return null;
    }
    /* YOUR PROCESSING DATA CODE */
    ...
    return null;
}
```

This way, pipeline will finish its job on the first of the month, but won't do any processing of your data...

Here you have an official example of making your own Custom Pipeline:
[Making your own custom pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities)

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but not cleanly, you'd need to break out PowerShell to manually override the time slices that you didn't want to run.

Create your datasets and provision the activities with a daily schedule for a year, or whatever. Once done use the PowerShell cmdlet **Set-AzureRmDataFactorySliceStatus** to override the time slice status for the 12 days in the year that you don't want to run. With the cmdlet if you use the **-Status** parameter with a value of **Skipped** that would avoid the execution.

For example:

```
Set-AzureRmDataFactorySliceStatus `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
    -DataFactoryName $ADFName.DataFactoryName `
    -DatasetName "YourDataset" `
    -StartDateTime 2016-12-01 `
    -EndDateTime 2016-12-02 `
    -Status "Skipped" `
    -UpdateType "Individual"
```

Then return this with different start and end dates.

This isn't perfect and would be something that you'd need to do post deployment of your pipeline. But it would offer the required behaviour.

More ADF PowerShell info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactories/set-azurermdatafactoryslicestatus?view=azurermps-4.0.0

Hope this helps.